# Collectios, cant add new elements

Tags: java, collections

I'm making simple program, which colled garage. So I have Car class, which contains 1 String field, 1 double field, and 3 ojects of my classes (Engine, GearBox, FuelTank). Also I have Garage Class which contains 1 fild, ArrayList of Cars. In my MainApp Class with main function I have menu method. At start I'm adding 3 objects to my List using Collections method add(). And to this place it works normally. But than when I try to add new object to my collection using method addCar in my Garage Class, all goes quit normal, at the and of this option it shows my collection with new element, but when I try to show my collection again using option [5] it shows me only 3 elements that I add on start. Sort and remove also don't work.

Garage.java:

```
package ua.lviv.anax;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import java.util.Collections;

import java.util.List;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Garage {

    private List<Car> garage = new ArrayList<>();


    public Garage() {
    }

    public void addCar() {
        String model = scanner("Enter car model");
        double consumationOfFuel = Double
                .parseDouble(scanner("Enter fuel consumation in liters per km"));
        double volume = Double.parseDouble(scanner("Enter engine volume"));
        int hp = Integer.parseInt(scanner("Enter engine power"));
        boolean auto = Boolean
                .parseBoolean(scanner("Is your gearbox automatic (true/false)"));
        int gearsCount = Integer.parseInt(scanner("Enter gear count"));
        String gearBoxType = scanner("Enter gearBox type");
        double amountOfFuel = Double
                .parseDouble(scanner("Enter amount of fuel in your tank"));
        double capacity = Double
                .parseDouble(scanner("Enter your tank capacity"));
        this.garage.add(new Car(model, consumationOfFuel, volume, hp, auto,
                gearsCount, gearBoxType, amountOfFuel, capacity));

    }

    public void removeCar(int index) {
        if (indexCheck(index)) {
        } else
            garage.remove(index);
    }

    public void rideCar(int index, int km) {
        if (indexCheck(index)) {
        } else
            garage.get(index - 1).ride(km);
    }

    public void showGarage() {
        for (int i = 0; i < garage.size(); i++) {
            System.out.println(i + 1 + ". " + garage.get(i).getModel() + " "
                    + garage.get(i).getEngine().getVolume() + " " +garage.get(i).getEngine().getHp() +" " +garage.get(i).getFuelTank().getAmount() +" " + garage.get(i).getGearBox().getGearsCount() + " "
                    + garage.get(i).getGearBox().getType());
        }
    }

    public void sortGarage(int indexOfSort) {
        switch (indexOfSort) {
        case 1:
            Collections.sort(this.garage, new ModelComparator());
            break;
        case 2:
            Collections.sort(this.garage, new AmountOfFuelComparator());
            break;
        case 3:
            Collections.sort(this.garage, new VolumeComparator());
            break;
        case 4:
            Collections.sort(this.garage, new GearsCountComparator());
            break;
        default:
            System.out
                    .println("You entered wrong number, please try again and enter correct one");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        String garageStr = garage.toString();
        return garageStr;
    }

    public List<Car> getGarage() {
        return garage;
    }

    public void setGarage(List<Car> garage) {
        this.garage = garage;
    }

    public boolean indexCheck(int index) {
        if (index <= 0 && index > garage.size()) {
            System.out
                    .println("You entered wrong number, plese try again and enter correct one");
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    public String scanner(String msg) {
        System.out.println(msg);
        @SuppressWarnings("resource")
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        String scannedString = scan.nextLine();
        return scannedString;
    }

}
```

Car.java:

```
package ua.lviv.anax;

public class Car {

    private String model;

    private double consumptionOfFuel;

    private Engine engine;

    private GearBox gearBox;

    private FuelTank fuelTank;


    public Car() {
    }
    public Car(String model, double consumptionOfFuel, double volume, int hp, boolean auto, int gearsCount, String gearBoxType, double amount, double capacity){
        this.model=model;
        this.consumptionOfFuel=consumptionOfFuel;
        this.engine=new Engine(volume, hp);
        this.gearBox=new GearBox(auto, gearsCount, gearBoxType);
        this.fuelTank= new FuelTank(amount, capacity);
    }
    public String getModel() {
        return model;
    }
    public void setModel(String model) {
        this.model = model;
    }

    public double getConsumptionOfFuel() {
        return consumptionOfFuel;
    }
    public void setConsumptionOfFuel(int consumptionOfFuel) {
        this.consumptionOfFuel = consumptionOfFuel;
    }
    public Engine getEngine() {
        return engine;
    }
    public void setEngine(double volume, int hp) {
        this.engine = new Engine(volume, hp);
    }
    public GearBox getGearBox() {
        return gearBox;
    }
    public void setGearBox(boolean auto, int gearsCount, String type) {
        this.gearBox = new GearBox(auto, gearsCount, type);
    }
    public FuelTank getFuelTank() {
        return fuelTank;
    }
    public void setFuelTank(double amount, double capacity) {
        this.fuelTank = new FuelTank(amount, capacity);
    }
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Car [model=" + model + ", engine=" + engine + ", gearBox="
                + gearBox + ", fuelTank=" + fuelTank + "]";
    }
    public void ride(int km){
        double kmDone=fuelTank.getAmount()*100/consumptionOfFuel;
        fuelTank.useFuel(km*consumptionOfFuel/100);
        if (fuelTank.getAmount()==0){
            System.out.println("Your out of fuel, you have passed "+kmDone+" kilomeeters");
        }
    }
}
```

Engine.java:

```
package ua.lviv.anax;

public class Engine {

    private double volume;

    private int hp;

    public Engine() {

    }

    public Engine(double volume, int hp) {
        this.volume = volume;
        this.hp = hp;
    }

    public double getVolume() {
        return volume;
    }

    public void setVolume(double volume) {
        this.volume = volume;
    }

    public int getHp() {
        return hp;
    }

    public void setHp(int hp) {
        this.hp = hp;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Engine [volume=" + volume + ", hp=" + hp + "]";
    }



}
```

Gearbox.java:

```
package ua.lviv.anax;

public class GearBox {

    private boolean auto;

    private int gearsCount;

    private String type;

    public GearBox() {
    }

    public GearBox(boolean auto, int gearsCount, String type) {
        this.auto = auto;
        this.gearsCount = gearsCount;
        this.type = type;
    }

    public boolean isAuto() {
        return auto;
    }

    public void setAuto(boolean auto) {
        this.auto = auto;
    }

    public int getGearsCount() {
        return gearsCount;
    }

    public void setGearsCount(int gearsCount) {
        this.gearsCount = gearsCount;
    }

    public String getType() {
        return type;
    }

    public void setType(String type) {
        this.type = type;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "GearBox [auto=" + auto + ", gearsCount=" + gearsCount
                + ", type=" + type + "]";
    }

}
```

FuelTank.java:

```
package ua.lviv.anax;

public class FuelTank {

    private double amount;

    private double capacity;

    public FuelTank() {
    }

    public FuelTank(double amount, double capacity) {
        this.amount = amount;
        this.capacity = capacity;
    }

    public double getAmount() {
        return amount;
    }

    public void setAmount(double amount) {
        this.amount = amount;
    }

    public double getCapacity() {
        return capacity;
    }

    public void setCapacity(double capacity) {
        this.capacity = capacity;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "FuelTank [amount=" + amount + ", capacity=" + capacity + "]";
    }

    public void useFuel(double amount){
        this.amount -=amount;
        if(this.amount<=0){
            this.amount=0;
        }
    }
}
```

MainApp.java:

```
package ua.lviv.anax;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class MainApp {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        new MainApp().menu();
    }

    public void menu(){

        System.out.println("Welcome to garage");

        while(true){
            System.out.println("Please enter [1] to add car:");
            System.out.println("Please enter [2] to remove car:");
            System.out.println("Please enter [3] to ride a car:");
            System.out.println("Please enter [4] to sort cars in garage:");
            System.out.println("Please enter [5] to show garage:");
            System.out.println("Enter [10] to exit.");
            Garage garage = new Garage();
            garage.getGarage().add(new Car("BMW M5", 17.8, 6.0, 575, true, 6, "Tip Tronic", 55, 80));
            garage.getGarage().add(new Car("Mercedes E63", 16.5, 6.3, 565, true, 7, "Tip Tronic", 45, 90));
            garage.getGarage().add(new Car("Audi RS6", 17.5, 5.5, 602, true, 7, "Tip Tronic", 25, 90));
            switch(scanner()){

            case 1:
                garage.addCar();
                garage.showGarage();
                break;

            case 2:
                garage.showGarage();
                System.out.println("Please enter the index of car you want to remove");
                garage.removeCar(scanner());
                break;

            case 3:
                garage.showGarage();
                System.out.println("Please enter number of car you want to ride");
                int index = scanner();
                System.out.println("Please enter number of kilometers you want to go");
                int km=scanner();
                garage.rideCar(index, km);
                break;

            case 4:
                System.out.println("Enter a number of type sort");
                System.out.println("Enter [1] for sort by hp:");
                System.out.println("Enter [2] for sort by amount of fuel:");
                System.out.println("Enter [3] for sort by volume:");
                System.out.println("Enter [4] for sort by gear count:");

                int indexOfSort = scanner();
                garage.sortGarage(indexOfSort);
                break;
            case 5:
                System.out.println(garage);
                System.out.println("==========================");
                break;
            case 10:
                System.exit(0);
            default:
                System.out.println("You entered wrong number, please try again and enter correct one");
            }

        }
    }

    public int scanner(){
        @SuppressWarnings("resource")
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        int scannedInt = scan.nextInt();
        return scannedInt;
    }
}
```

And this is my try to add car into garage:

```
Please enter [1] to add car:

Please enter [2] to remove car:

Please enter [3] to ride a car:

Please enter [4] to sort cars in garage:

Please enter [5] to show garage:

Enter [10] to exit.
1
Enter car model

VW

Enter fuel consumation in liters per km

5

Enter engine volume

1.2

Enter engine power

55

Is your gearbox automatic (true/false)

true

Enter gear count

5

Enter gearBox type

Basic Auto

Enter amount of fuel in your tank

20

Enter your tank capacity

55

1. BMW M5 6.0 575 55.0 6 Tip Tronic

2. Mercedes E63 6.3 565 45.0 7 Tip Tronic

3. Audi RS6 5.5 602 25.0 7 Tip Tronic

4. VW 1.2 55 20.0 5 Basic Auto

Please enter [1] to add car:

Please enter [2] to remove car:

Please enter [3] to ride a car:

Please enter [4] to sort cars in garage:

Please enter [5] to show garage:

Enter [10] to exit.

5

[Car [model=BMW M5, engine=Engine [volume=6.0, hp=575], gearBox=GearBox [auto=true,

 gearsCount=6, type=Tip Tronic], fuelTank=FuelTank [amount=55.0, capacity=80.0]], 

Car [model=Mercedes E63, engine=Engine [volume=6.3, hp=565], gearBox=GearBox [auto=true, 

gearsCount=7, type=Tip Tronic], fuelTank=FuelTank [amount=45.0, capacity=90.0]], 

Car [model=Audi RS6, engine=Engine [volume=5.5, hp=602], 

gearBox=GearBox [auto=true, gearsCount=7, type=Tip Tronic], fuelTank=FuelTank [amount=25.0, capacity=90.0]]]
==========================


Please enter [1] to add car:

Please enter [2] to remove car:

Please enter [3] to ride a car:

Please enter [4] to sort cars in garage:

Please enter [5] to show garage:

Enter [10] to exit.

10
```

Like you see after option 1 the new Car is shown, but after calling option 5, its only 3 elements that was on start.

Comment: This amount of code is overwhelming. Please consider narrowing your problem down.

Comment: Thanks for formatting my question, ill try to format it better next time.

Comment: sry everyone, founded mistake, sry for your time, and excuse me once more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have initialize your `Garage` class object inside while loop. Take that out side while loop.
Every time your while loop execute it will initialize your `Garage` class object, which turn your newly enter data will be overwrite by the your three value initialize at starting of while loop.
You should be :

```
Garage garage = new Garage();  
 while(true){
            System.out.println("Please enter [1] to add car:");
            System.out.println("Please enter [2] to remove car:");  
            //Reset of your code
```

Answer (score 0):

I put creating Garage object into menu loop, and every time I tried to do next action, I was creating new Garage object, and fill it with my objects at start.

Excuse me everyone who spend his time on reading my code and looking for mistake.

Comment: Why not simply delete your question?